# Use a TypeScript enum as an Angular template variable name with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, enums, angular2-template, ng-template, ng-container

I have looked at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923744/pass-enums-in-angular2-view-templates). But it doesn't quite answer my question. **I want to bind the local variable name to the enum's value** like in the following (heavily simplified) example:

In **`certain-state.component.ts`**:

```
export enum CertainState {
    VALID,
    INVALID
}

export class CertainStateComponent {
    // holder for the current state
    public state: CertainState;

    // store the actual enum in the instance of the class so that
    // it is available in the template
    public certainStates: typeof CertainState = CertainState;

    // below is the logic which sets the state
    ...
}
```

In **`certain-state.component.html`**:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="state_{{state}}"></ng-container>

// obviously this is invalid syntax but I want to demonstrate my intention
<ng-template #state_{{certainStates.VALID}}><span>VALID</span></ng-template>
<ng-template #state_{{certainStates.INVALID}}><span>INVALID</span></ng-template>
```

**EDIT:**
I think the solution is in the following answer: [How to use a typescript enum value in an Angular2 ngSwitch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835984/how-to-use-a-typescript-enum-value-in-an-angular2-ngswitch-statement/35835985). What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

This is what `CertainState` enum really is:

```
(function (CertainState) {
    CertainState[CertainState["VALID"] = 0] = "VALID";
    CertainState[CertainState["INVALID"] = 1] = "INVALID";
})(CertainState = exports.CertainState || (exports.CertainState = {}));
```

It basically maps keys to indexes and vice versa.

So it should be typed like:

```
public state: number;
public certainStates: typeof CertainState = CertainState;
```

And if state name is supposed to be used, it can be looked up on enum:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="state_{{certainStates[state]}}"></ng-container>
<ng-template #state_{{certainStates[certainStates.VALID]}}><span>VALID</span></ng-template>
```

Or enum index can be used directly:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="state_{{state}}"></ng-container>
<ng-template #state_{{certainStates.VALID}}><span>VALID</span></ng-template>
```

Enums aren't the best choice for cases where a key may be used as a string, because they require extra lookup and don't allow strict typing. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099594/3731501), plain object is generally a better choice for looser typing, and a namespace is good for stricter typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public certainStates: typeof CertainState = CertainState;
```

should be

```
public certainStates: any = CertainState;
```

or

```
public certainStates: {[s: number]: string } = CertainState;
```

Comment: Your solution throws "Type 'typeof CertainState' is not assignable to type 'CertainState'."

Comment: I updated my answer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785209/217408

Comment: Why so? `typeof CertainState` is valid type and should work as expected.

Comment: Seems to be passed as object, not as type in an assignment.