# How to use enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript2.0

I have the following enum:

```
export enum SubstitutionType {
  REPLACEMENT_TEACHER_SUBJECT = 0,
  REPLACEMENT_TEACHER = 1,
  REPLACEMENT_FREE = 2
}
```

I try to user this in class like this:

```
class A {

public substitutionsType: SubstitutionType;

}
```

Then in template I can not get access to `substitutionsType` like this:

```
substitutionsType.REPLACEMENT_FREE
```

Why, how to use this?

Comment: what do you mean by template?

Comment: I mean template Angular 2, so maybe to to this: `public substitutionsType = SubstitutionType;`?

Comment: There is already an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923744/pass-enums-in-angular2-view-templates

Comment: since it's a type, replace your = by a column :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass enums in angular2 view templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923744/pass-enums-in-angular2-view-templates) as per [Niladri's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692387/how-to-use-enum-in-typescript/49692472#comment86396757_49692387).

Comment: Here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40034109/9579547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this help you:

```
export enum SubstitutionType {
  REPLACEMENT_TEACHER_SUBJECT,
  REPLACEMENT_TEACHER,
  REPLACEMENT_FREE
}
```

To use it in a template you should  export a class like this this:

```
export class Substitutions{
    public substitutionsType: SubstitutionType; 

    @Input() public set substitution(val: number) {
        console.log(value);
    };
}
```

Then to use it in your template you will write something like this:

```
<span class="Substitutions" subsitutionType="subsitution.REPLACEMENT_FREE"></span>
```

I used this post like an example: [Pass enums in angular2 view templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923744/pass-enums-in-angular2-view-templates)

Comment: I know it allows to use only one values, maybe replace enum to dictionary?

Comment: @dooglu I edited the post. If you use angular i could say how to binding with a property of a component.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you declare `substitutionsType` to be of type `SubstitutionType`, i.e. it can hold one of the enumeration values. What you want to achieve, however, is to assign the (whole) enumeration to the instance variable:

```
class A {
    public substitutionsType = SubstitutionType;
}

// Now typechecks
(new A).substitutionsType.REPLACEMENT_FREE;
```

The inferred type of the instance variable is `typeof SubstitutionType`, which you can also annotate if you like.

Comment: It is not convinient and I must pass `(new A).substitutionsType.REPLACEMENT_FREE;` to template.

Comment: So, creating instance if class A is bad idea

Comment: Why it does not work: `public type() {
    return this;
  }`     Then `type().substitutionsType.REPLACEMENT_FREE`

Comment: @dooglu Have a look at the linked duplicate question. Actually, I am voting to close this question as the linked one has your answer.

Comment: Here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40034109/9579547